# Jenkins job lost upon restart even though configuration is on the disk

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

I have restarted Jenkins using the following:

```
service jenkins stop
service jenkins start
```

Followed to that I can see some jobs are missing from the GUI.

I have also tried to go the job URL using `http://<jenkins_url>/job/<JOBNAME>/`

Unfortunately it is also giving:

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /job/<JOBNAME>/. Reason:

    Not Found

Powered by Jetty://
```

Also performed Doing a `Reload Configuration from Disk` with no luck.

I checked the config.xml file and I can see it is corrupted. The size of config.xml file is around 110 MB. Why this file got corrupted? How to trace it.

Can anyone give me any pointer how to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Can you still see the jobs if you go to <jenkins_url>/job/<job_name> ?  Jenkins doesn't load all jobs at startup in order to reduce startup time, but you should see the job if you go to its specific URL.

Comment: I tried to go to <jenkins_url>/job/<job_name>. And it is giving me the error: Problem accessing /job/<JOBNMAE>/. Reason: Not Found

Comment: Troubleshoot by going to the actual folder that URL responds to on the Jenkins Server and checking if all the files are still there. `D:\Jenkins\jobs\<jobname>` ... Check that the config.xml isn't corrupt or contain garbage information. Also, suggested restarting using `http://jenkins:8080/restart` next time

Comment: Judging by your edits I guess I'm getting closer.. If you haven't been keeping backups of your Jenkins Folder then you just have to try to restore the congfig.xml manually. The logs should be throwing exceptions when Jenkins tries to load the jobs, that may be of help.

Comment: I had a similar issue - I got around it by creating a new job with the same name as the missing one.  After saving it the original configuration of the missing job was picked up.  i haven't seen this issue with more recent versions of Jenkins though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms, but I'm using a homebrew installation of Jenkins.

The Jenkins machine was shut down improperly, likely from a power outage, so when it came back up it was basically a clean instance. No jobs and no system configurations.

The following solution isn't for your exact use case, but it does solve the problem for some users who return to Jenkins to find it without any jobs.

The solution basically involves you checking to see if you have started the Jenkins service incorrectly or from the wrong place.

...

On to the specific homebrew issue:

For whatever reason, the `homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist` file was found in `~/Library/LaunchDaemons/`

It belongs in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` only.

If this happens, it can be solved as follows

1. Stop the service:
   `sudo launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist`
2. Reload the correct file, located in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` by trying the following line in case it's running:
   `launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist`

   Note: the above line may yell at you if it's not running, which is ok.
3. Start it up again:
   `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist`
4. If all looks good when Jenkins loads again, you can and should
   delete `homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist` in `~/Library/LaunchDaemons/`:
   `sudo rm ~/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist`